# Equivalence norm in $W^{s, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and Gagliardo seminorm $[u]_{s, p}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I am reading a paper and the in the first pages it is written what follows.

> Let $s\in (0, 1), p>1$, $n> sp$ and $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with Lipschitz boundary. Let
> $$
> [u]_{s,p} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^p}{|x - y|^{n+sp}}\, dx dy\right)^{1/p}
> $$
> be the Gagliardo seminorm of the measurable function $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and let
> $$
> W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) : [u]_{s,p} < \infty\}
> $$
> be the fractional Sobolev space endowed with the norm
> $$
> \|u\|_{s, p} = \big(|u|_p^p + [u]_{s,p}^p\big)^{1/p},
> $$
> where $|\cdot|_p$ is the norm in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Consider the closed linear subspace
> $$
> X_p^s(\Omega) = \{u \in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) : u = 0 \text{ a.e. in } \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega\},
> $$
> equivalently renormed by setting $\|\cdot\|_{s, p} = [\cdot]_{s,p}$.

Could someone please help me in proving that $\|\cdot\|_{s, p}$ and $[\cdot]_{s,p}$ are equivalent norms in $X^s_p (\Omega)$?
Actually, I am interested in proving only that there exists $c>0$ such that
$$\|u\|_{s, p} \le c [u]_{s, p}$$
since I have proved on my own the inequality in the other direction.

Also, which role plays the fact that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, one of the direction is trivial since $a\leq a+b$ if $b\geq 0$. For the other direction, by Sobolev's embedding, $\|u\|_{L^q(\Omega)} \leq C\,[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}$ for $q = \frac{np}{n -sp} > p$, and since the domain is bounded $\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C_\Omega\,\|u\|_{L^q(\Omega)}$ by Hölder's inequality.